# Каждый месяц Facebook использует (или "используют") 1,8 миллиарда человек

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование

В одном фейсбучном сообществе людей позабавило такое сообщение:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно представить, что это платформа Facebook использует людей, а не они используют платформу Facebook.

Я заглянул [на сайт gramota.ru](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/64-bolshinstvo):

> Согласование сказуемого со словами «тысяча, миллион, миллиард»
>
> Сказуемое при словах тысяча, миллион, миллиард обычно принимает форму подлежащего (единственное число, женский или мужской род). Тысяча человек каждый год отдыхает в этом санатории. Миллион тюльпанов посажен на клумбе.

Но, с другой стороны:

> Согласование по смыслу предпочтительно:
>
> 3) если нужно подчеркнуть раздельность действий каждого действующего лица, называемого подлежащим, а также подчеркнуть активность действующих лиц: Ряд сотрудников нашей организации выступили с инициативой; ср.: В прошлом году было построено множество дорог.

Насколько я понял, "использует" не является ошибкой, но всё-таки предпочтительнее писать "используют"?

Comment: Вы слишком верите в человечество. Исходная фраза читается правильно, субъектом действия в ней является Фейсбук.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как уже было сказано, написанное не является ошибкой. Боюсь, нет объективного ответа на вопрос, что предпочтительно в данном случае. 
Аргументы в пользу единственного числа: желание обратить внимание на количество, а не на активность действующих лиц, наличие слова "более" (обозначение приблизительного количества). В пользу множественного числа -  только **устранение двусмысленности** (кто кого использует), но, на мой взгляд, этот аргумент **важнее остальных.**
А еще замечу, что двусмысленность можно устранить, употребив прямой порядок слов: **"Каждый месяц более 1.8 миллиарда человек использует Facebook".** И волки сыты, и овцы целы.

---

Дополнение

А вообще-то Фейсбук не используют, им пользуются. Так что рекламу эту нужно менять.

Comment: *только устран[ен]ие неоднозначности* - о какой неоднозначности речь? Может, я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: @Morkovkin   Устранение двусмысленности (кто кого использует) - так яснее?

Comment: Вы серьезно? Вроде у даже у автора такого не было, когда я отвечал - точно не видел. Это ему потом уже "отредактировали". Ну ладно, допустим...  Интересно, у Розенталя подобное соображение о неоднозначности есть? У "Грамоты" нет точно"

Comment: Черт знает, Розенталь о том умалчивает. http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm

Comment: @Morkovkin  Во-первых, надеюсь Вы согласны, что двусмысленность имеет место? Во-вторых, можно, наверно, найти цитату о том, что двусмысленность не есть хорошо, но это как бы само собой разумеется. А раз правила не строгие, то по-моему, лучше выбрать вариант, лишенный двусмусленности.

Comment: АГ - тоже. Может, действительно, и есть неоднозначность... Но как аргумент выбора варианта согласования не встречалось.

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку в вашем случае возможна двусмысленность (и вы сами на нее указали), лучше использовать множественное число. Всё же очень просто. Это не тот случай, когда нужно "растекаться мыслию по древу".

Answer (score -2):

Нет, вы не так поняли. Вернее сказать - не дочитали до конца.

Сразу скажу, в отношении мнения (неподписанного) "Грамоты": имейте в виду, что авторитетным источником сайт не является. Там много авторов и зачастую один другому противоречит. Правда, в данном случае, они ссылаются на "академическую грамматику", но все равно не стоит так уж слепо доверять. В данном случае меня смущает слово "обычно", что оставляет свободу для любого понимания.

Но дело даже не в этом. Вым не учли того, что в вашем примере идет согласование не с числительным как таковым, а с конструкцией типа "более", ("больше, чем"), а в этом случае само числительное мало, его тип мало что определяет.

Вот что по этому поводу говорит сама "Грамота":

> Согласование сказуемого при обозначении подлежащим приблизительного
>   количества
>
> При подлежащем – количественном сочетании со значением
>   приблизительности ***предпочитается форма единственного числа сказуемого***:
>   Откроется несколько новых школ. На земле живет более трех миллиардов
>   людей.  Но: Лишь несколько студентов смогли решить эту задачу; форма
>   множественного числа сказуемого обусловлена  «активностью» действующих
>   лиц, названных подлежащим.
>   (там же, курсив мой)

Здесь тот же прокол стиля изложения ("предпочитается" вместо прямого указания, в каких конкретно случаях следует использовать ту или иную форму), но тем не менее рекомендация "Справки" понятно.

***Вне зависимости от самого числительного при словах следует согласовывать с единственным числом. Но если важно подчеркнуть активность действующего лица и/или логическую его "собирательность", то множественное допустимо.***

Пример из ФБ в принципе допускает интерпретацию активности, хотя собирательности тут не просматривается.

Так что исходный вариант примера в ФБ - предпочтителен для нейтрального сообщения, а множественное число может быть употребимо для стилистического выделения, акцента.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58459/discussion-on-answer-by-morkovkin---facebook---).